# How To Swipe Image in Ios Using CollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

I have create this screen by using `CollectionView Controller`.

[image]

When I click on any image then, it will show their image. I have created by using `Navigation controller` and tried this.

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    obj_NavigationViewController = [[NavigationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NavigationViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj_NavigationViewController animated:YES];

    obj_NavigationViewController.obj_String= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld of %lu ",(long)indexPath.row,(unsigned long)[obj_Image count]];

    obj_NavigationViewController.obj_ImageCollection = [obj_Image objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



}
```

Now it works. But what I want is, when I click on certain image afterwards or swipe, then it should display another image. But currently not working, please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: not working in what way?  Have you added a gesture recogniser to the UIImageView?  Is it being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UIScrollView and calculate content size as per your images count or use 3rd party library MWPhotoBrowser.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Scrollview to display your images . as @maulik Bhuptani suggested MWPhotoBrowser is pretty good library to use and perfect for you need.You can achieve the functionality in booth ways.